# remove route with google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I got a small app that use the Direction Service feature of Google  Map. It is working well, I can change routes, but I have a small problem, where a user could go back to a list of markers after tracing a route.

I can't find a way to delete routes with google map. For markers I store them and do `setMap(null)`, do not see a way here...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

if you are using DirectionsRenderer to display the routes, you can call setMap(null) on it too. That way you delete the displayed route.

Using the example code here
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple.html

just call

```
directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
```

Comment: If you do this, it just comes back when you try to overwrite with another route, so you get both routes showing on the map.

Comment: That's not true! I just tested in a small POC. When you run `directionsDisplay.setDirections(directions)` and add the renderer back to the map with `directionsDisplay.setMap(map)` it works correctly. It only displays one path (the contents of `directions` variable). There must be some other problem in your code.

Comment: This works to remove the directionsDisplay object from your map, but if you are replacing one route with another it just adds the replaced one to the map.

Comment: Like ajbraus said, 2 or more routes are displayed. Not cleaned.

Comment: See my answer below which fixed the issue

Answer (score 63):

You could also use:

```
directionsDisplay.setDirections({routes: []});
```

In this way, you can keep using one map with one renderer for all routes.

Comment: This is a better solution for me because if you try to get directions again the first solution will throw a JS error.

However, I did
`directionsDisplay.setDirections({routes: []});`

Comment: I agree, using the literal is a better solution than the use of the new keyword, I've updated my answer.

Comment: This didn't allow me to keep using the same map. It just stacks the routes on top of each other on the same map.

Comment: @ajbraus It's possible the API has been changed since I answered this, I haven't checked it in a while. Please consider the date of an answer before downvoting something.

Comment: @Anzeo if your answer is out of date, it makes sense to down vote it.

Comment: ajbraus, you don't provide your code, and I can only assume your code has some other error.   Most likely a scope issue.

Comment: This is a better solution for me also. The other solution directionsDisplay.setMap(null) removes your map instance from the google.maps.DirectionsService(); instance, so if you try to draw a route after that a JS error is shown. This method directionsDisplay.setDirections({routes: []}); keeps your map instance attached the directionsService instance, so you can draw routes again using the same service, without having to re attach your map to the directionsService instance

Comment: Please note that you will need a instance of DirectionsRenderer to persist between to sessions for the emptying of the routes to take effect.

Answer (score 9):

The other answers did not work for me. I found a solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568499/remove-previous-directions-route-google-maps)

define `directionsDisplay` only 1 time(outside of the `click`-handler)

Answer (score 8):

This is the fix

```
// Clear past routes
if (directionsDisplay != null) {
    directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
    directionsDisplay = null;
}
```

Comment: most helpful answer!

Answer (score 7):

Since on each call, new instance of DirectionRenderer created thats why each new instance is unaware of previous instance.

Move

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
```

to the global(at the top where all other Global variables have been initialized.)

By doing so, each time you would be using single instance of DirectionRenderer.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, I tried with `directionsDisplay.setMap(null);` but it didn’t work.

The problem was the `directionsDisplay` object which I created was declared locally.

I changed it to global and every time the function is called, it will use the same global `directionsDisplay` object and make changes to it. This will definitely remove the previous route displayed on same object.

Answer (score 1):

It's important - at least it was in my case - that while `directionsDisplay` can be declared globally the instance has to be created after the map object otherwise it gave a reference error

```
    var map;
    var directionsDisplay;

    function initMap() { 

        map = new google.maps.Map(...);

        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(...);

     }

     function yourFunction() {

        // your code

        directionsDisplay.addListener(...);

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

set   strokeWeight: 0 then polyline will hide