# Remove previous Directions Route Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

> Hi, I am trying to plan a route from the info window, but i am unable
>   to remove the previous set route. I tried setMap(null) but it didn't
>   work. I am using a callback for an event listener as i need to pass parameter which is returned from an api call. One option is to use new google.maps.map on each event e.g ([link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple?csw=1)) on marker but than my markers are already placed when the page loads.

```
element = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
map = new google.maps.Map(element, options);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(car.lat, car.long),
    map: map,
    title: car.make
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', directionsCallback(car));
function directionsCallback(car) {
    return function (e) {
        if( infowindow != null ) {
            infowindow.close();
        }
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
        console.log(directionsDisplay);
        calcRoute = function(){
            var startPoint = document.getElementById('clientAddress').value;
            var finishPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(car.lat, car.long);
            var request = {
                origin: startPoint,
                destination: finishPoint,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    console.log(directionsDisplay)
                    console.log(response.routes.length)
                    infowindow.close();
                }
                else{
                    alert('Sorry ! ' + givenAddress + ' not recognized')
                }
            });
        }
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        infowindow.setContent("\n"
            + 'Directions to here : <input id = \'clientAddress\'       placeholder=\"Postcode or City\" type=\'text\'>'
            + ' <input type=\'button\' onClick=calcRoute() value=\'Go!\'>')
        infowindow.open(map, this);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

define `directionsDisplay`  only 1 time(outside of the `click`-handler)

Comment: Thanks very much , it works. Could you please explain why it  worked ? Was i rendering driectionsDisplay on each click before setting it to null (setMap(null))

Comment: A `DirectionsRenderer`-instance(`directionsDisplay` in your code) may only draw a single route, so when you set a new route a previous route will be removed automatically. But you should leave it as it is(the calls of `setMap`), otherwise it will happen that a previous route will not be removed when the call of `directionsService.route` didn't return a result.