# AngularJS ui-gmap-google-map remove driving route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using AngularJS and the ui-gmap-google-map directive (http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) I've created a google map that plots the route to drive. When I try to plot a different route, the first route remains on the map. I've tried directionsDisplay.setMap(null); to remove the old route, but this isn't working. Can anyone help?

Here is the relevant part of my controller code:

```
uiGmapIsReady.promise().then(function (map_instances) {
                $scope.mapRef = $scope.map.control.getGMap();
            });

$scope.getDirections = function (lat, long, origin, type) {
            uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function (maps) {
                var directionsService = new maps.DirectionsService();
                var directionsDisplay = new maps.DirectionsRenderer();

                if (origin == "" || type == "geo") {
                    origin = $scope.geoPosition.coords.latitude + ", " + $scope.geoPosition.coords.longitude;
                }

                var request = {
                    origin: origin,
                    destination: lat + ", " + long,
                    travelMode: maps.TravelMode['DRIVING'],
                    optimizeWaypoints: true
                };

                directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
                        directionsDisplay.setMap($scope.mapRef);
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

                    } else {
                        console.log('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                    }
                });


            });
        }
```

Comment: The thing is you can either call map.remove() or remove a specific layer where the route is displayed normally when you console.log you $scope.mapRef there should be Layers in there

Comment: Won't map.remove get rid of the entire map? Can you tell me the best way to remove the existing route?

Comment: try that directionsDisplay.setMap(null); or directionsService.setMap(null)

Comment: I've already tried that as you can see in my example, but that doesn't work.

Comment: read here there are multiple ways http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232756/remove-route-with-google-map

Comment: None of those work either.

Comment: that is pretty weird are you sure you can access directionService from where you are calling it? or directionDisplay?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, since I can set the directions on the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is that you keep creating
`var directionsDisplay = new maps.DirectionsRenderer();` each time you get a new direction. Instead what you should do is create that variable when you initiate the Controller and then update it later on. I created a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/7tEeOXy9rHY2b7gMMw9x?p=preview)

You can see if this update to your code helps

```
uiGmapIsReady.promise().then(function (map_instances) {
    $scope.mapRef = $scope.map.control.getGMap();
    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function (maps) {
        $scope.directionsDisplay = new maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    });
});

$scope.getDirections = function (lat, long, origin, type) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function (maps) {
        var directionsService = new maps.DirectionsService();

        if (origin == "" || type == "geo") {
            origin = $scope.geoPosition.coords.latitude + ", " + $scope.geoPosition.coords.longitude;
        }

        var request = {
            origin: origin,
            destination: lat + ", " + long,
            travelMode: maps.TravelMode['DRIVING'],
            optimizeWaypoints: true
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                $scope.directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
                $scope.directionsDisplay.setMap($scope.mapRef);
                $scope.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

            } else {
                console.log('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
        });


    });
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 4):

I know you are working with ui-map, but with [ngmap](http://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps), you may have less problem

The following is example with ngmap showing two directions and you can toggle it to show and hide directions.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Sv9Q4A?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ngMap">
  <head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=weather,visualization,panoramio"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('ngMap').controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
  var vm = this;
  vm.toggle = function() {
    vm.show = !vm.show;
    $scope.map.directionsRenderers.d1.setMap(vm.show ? $scope.map : null);
  }
})
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller='MyCtrl as vm'>
    <map zoom="14" center="37.7699298, -122.4469157">
      <directions id="d1" origin="toronto" destination="markham"></directions>
      <directions id="d2" origin="etobicoke" destination="vaughn, on"></directions>
    </map> 
    <a href="" ng-click="vm.toggle()">show/hide direction</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Btw, I am the creator of ngMap.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already spent enough time with the existing map and have everything working except being able to remove a driving route.

Comment: no problem, just wanted to share other ways to do it.