# clear direction route on google maps

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Having a weird problem. I have a map set up with various markers. On the infoWindow you can click to "get directions" that triggers an onClick... first time route get's displayed correctly but if click another marker and ask for directions ... the previous direction route doesn't get cleared from the map when the new one is drawn

I already tried somethings, more specifically solutions provided on this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232756/remove-route-with-google-map) but nothing seems to work.

My code is this:

```
    function getDirections(id) {

        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

        var start = document.getElementById('pos1').innerHTML;
        var end = document.getElementById('pos'+id).innerHTML;

        end = end.slice(0, -1);
        end = end.substring(1);

        directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions'));

        directionsService.route({
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function(response, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                console.log(response);
            } else {
                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
        });

        disableMovement(false);
        infoWindow.close();

        var control = document.getElementById('directions');
        control.style.display = 'block';
        map.controls.push(control);
    }
```

And on this image you can see what I'm getting ... the previous route wasn't erased from the map before the new one got drawn.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in case anyone needs it in the future ...

These:

```
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
```

have to be outside the click event.